# Writing a script that will automatically follow and RT accounts based on specific keyword on Twitter but getting an error when I try to follow a user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Like I said, I am trying to write a script using Tweepy to follow and RT accounts based on a set of keywords. The script works for RT fine but throws up an error when trying to follow.

```
File "twitterraffle.py", line 19, in <module>
    api.retweet(id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'You have already retweeted this tweet.', u'code': 327}]
Jakes-MacBook-Pro:mystuff jakemills$ python twitterraffle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterraffle.py", line 20, in <module>
    if ('following' in result):
TypeError: argument of type 'Status' is not iterable
```

If I put the for loop to check if I must be following the account into a separate loop then the original one works fine. It is just when I try do them at the same time.

I have attached my code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = '***'
consumer_secret = '***'
access_token = '***'
access_token_secret = '***'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


results = api.search(q="RT to win", lang="en")


i = 1

for result in results:
    if ('following' in result):
        user_id = result.user_id
        api.create_friendship(user_id)
        print 'Followed'

    id = result.id
    api.retweet(id)
    print "Retweeting %s" % i
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: The documentation says that `API.search` returns a list of `SearchResult` objects. I don't see the `SearchResult` class documented, but it appears that the list may contain a mix of instances of various subclasses of `SearchResult`, some of which are iterable and others not.

Comment: So I cannot check for the User ID from the search results then I'm assuming that means.

Comment: You might; you'll just have to take more care. (At a minimum, you can could catch and ignore the `TypeError`, treating it as the same as a `False` result.)